# Link a:visited is superordinate

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, selector, visited

Is it possible to use link `a:visited` only when it is needed? When i do't use link `a:visited` it work fine except one or more mobile browsers (one browser). It show violet colored link. When i use link `a:visited` this selector is superordinate. I created [jsfiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/uxmrkxzz/) I know that i can use `a:visited` color same as `a:link` color but what if i want to use more as one links color? It show me all links with color defined in `a:visited` selector. How i can fix violet colored links on mobile browsers?

Comment: If you use for instance this `#link-motosport a:visited {color:#F00}` in your CSS, you directly and only create that CSS-rule for the `a-tag` INSIDE the element with `id="link-motosport"`. The other links won't be affected. This way you can create a different color for every link

Comment: sorry: `#link-motosport:visited {color:#F00}`, since that ID belongs to the `a-tag` itself

Comment: hi, i understand what you mean. But i highlight current opened link. So i can not use this way.

Comment: I think I don't fully understand your question then